# What happens if Iceland disappears?

Tags: environment, geology

In 2018, as if by magic, the entire island of Iceland suddenly disappears, along with all ground and sea down to 1km below sea level, all air up to 1km above sea level, and everything in or on the land, sea and air.

What effect does this have on the world?

Comment: A lot of things can happen. That makes this question too broad. You have to limit the question to some specific arena of consequences.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There will be a loud bang as the air rushes in to fill the one kilometre vacuum. A massive volcanic eruption as the magma from the Icelandic volcanoes is released. Seawater in rush into the one kilometre cavity where the island was and ran into the rising volcanic eruption.

Air travel in Europe and most of the Northern Hemisphere will be ruined due volcanic ash wrecking jet engines. There is the possibility of a [Toba](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toba_catastrophe_theory) scale event in the modern era.

> The Toba supereruption was a supervolcanic eruption that occurred about 75,000 years ago at the site of present-day Lake Toba in Sumatra, Indonesia. It is one of the Earth's largest known eruptions. The Toba catastrophe theory holds that this event caused a global volcanic winter of six to ten years and possibly a 1,000-year-long cooling episode.

Basically it won't be good. This suggests what could be the worst case outcome.

> The Toba eruption apparently coincided with the onset of the last glacial period. Michael L. Rampino and Stephen Self argue that the eruption caused a "brief, dramatic cooling or 'volcanic winter'", which resulted in a drop of the global mean surface temperature by 3–5 °C and accelerated the transition from warm to cold temperatures of the last glacial cycle.[12] Evidence from Greenland ice cores indicates a 1,000-year period of low δ18O and increased dust deposition immediately following the eruption. The eruption may have caused this 1,000-year period of cooler temperatures (stadial), two centuries of which could be accounted for by the persistence of the Toba stratospheric loading.[13] Rampino and Self believe that global cooling was already underway at the time of the eruption, but that the process was slow; YTT "may have provided the extra 'kick' that caused the climate system to switch from warm to cold states".[14] Although Clive Oppenheimer rejects the hypothesis that the eruption triggered the last glaciation,[15] he agrees that it may have been responsible for a millennium of cool climate prior to the 19th Dansgaard-Oeschger event.

The worst case scenario is effectively a nuclear winter if it results in a supervolcanic eruption. If Iceland disappears in the manner postulated by this question 2018 won't be a good year to be alive.